# How can I let vscode know when SCM visible or not?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to make toggle key with VScode's keybinding.
with alt + 1 to 5 to toggle explorer and search, scm, debug extension

I could find "explorerViewletVisible" or "searchViewletVisible"
But I couldn't find visibilities of scm (source control) and debug, extensions.
I use "sideBarVisible" for these key but it is not a perfect solution.
Does Anyone know right 'when expression' of these situations?

```
  {
    "key": "alt+1",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+1",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+2",
    "command": "workbench.view.search",
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+2",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "searchViewletVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+3",
    "command": "workbench.view.scm",
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+3",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "sideBarVisible"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

> But I couldn't find visibilities of scm (source control) and debug,
> extensions.

IF you want to require that the sideBar be focused as well as those views be opened.

`"when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"`

`"when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.debug'"`

`"when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extensions'"`

If you only want to ensure that those views be opened (and some other focus, like an editor is allowed), just remove the `sideBarFocus` part:

`"when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"`

`"when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.debug'"`

`"when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extensions'"`

Answer (score 3):

I found the way my self..
use 
"when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.explorer'"